# i want to use variable in sed -f command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am using this command to copy certain line from one file to another.Its working fine.No issue with it.

```
sed -f <(sed -e '1,10d; 12,$d; x; s/.*/10a\\/;p; x' ../log/file2.txt ) ../log/file4.txt > ../log/file5.txt
```

The problem is instead of 10, I want to use variable VAR1 (where var1=10).
The $VAR1 is not working.

I tried this command.

```
sed -f <(sed -e '1,$VAR1d; 12,$d; x; s/.*/10a\\/;p; x' ../log/file2.txt ) ../log/file4.txt > ../log/file5.txt
```

Please help me.

Comment: after replacing with double quote, its showing this error

Comment: see my answer: escape backslashes and dollars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, use double quotes. It will enable BASH to process string.

Next, escape backslashes (even those that supposed to be escape symbols for sed) - because bash will escape them too.

I suppose it should be

```
sed -f <(sed -e "1,${VAR1}d; 12,\$d; x; s/.*/10a\\\\/;p; x" ../log/file2.txt ) ../log/file4.txt > ../log/file5.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try double qoutes and curly braces:

```
 sed -f <(sed -e "1,${VAR1}d; 12,\$d; x; s/.*/10a\\\\/;p; x" ../log/file2.txt ) ../log/file4.txt > ../log/file5.txt
```

Comment: Curly braces is a good idea, although the problem were the single quotes. Double quotes do expand variables.

Comment: @fedorqui he curly braces are needed to separate var name and command.

Comment: Antigluk is right - I forgot the additional double escape for double backslash (now corrected)

Comment: @Matthias oh, you're right, otherwise it would like for the `VAR1d` variable

Answer (score 1):

I prefer mix of single & double quotes:

1. Single quotes around the text that must not be expanded. (Removes need to escape special characters.)
2. Double quotes around the text that needs to be expanded.

e.g. Your case would look like:

```
sed -f <(sed -e '1,'"$VAR1"'d; 12,$d; x; s/.*/10a\\/;p; x' ../log/file2.txt ) ../log/file4.txt > ../log/file5.txt
```